# using zip on dict keys and values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a bit confused by this paragraph in python docs for `dict` class

> If items(), keys(), values(), iteritems(), iterkeys(), and
>   itervalues() are called with no intervening modifications to the
>   dictionary, the lists will directly correspond. This allows the
>   creation of (value, key) pairs using zip(): pairs = zip(d.values(),
>   d.keys())

what is meant by `called with no intervening modifications` ?

if I  receive a dict instance which was spewed out by some function(I have no way of knowing if the elements were modified since the dict was created)..can I still use the `zip(d.values(),d.keys())` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

The point is you should not modify `d` between calling `d.values()` and `d.keys()`.

Comment: Interesting because the list comp runs faster for me on Python 2.7. `0.53 usec` for list comp compared to `0.692` usec for zip

Comment: @jamylak I'll remove that claim then.

Comment: Ok well here are the tests i did anyway: 

`python -m timeit -s "d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}" "[(y, x) for x, y in d.items()]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.527 usec per loop`

`python -m timeit -s "d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}" "zip(d.values(), d.keys())"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.685 usec per loop`

Comment: @jamylak -- running your tests, I get faster list-comps as well.  (1.4 usec vs 1.72 usec python 2.7.3, OS-X) and 1.38 usec vs. 1.65 usec on python 2.6.4)

Comment: I tried a new test where `zip` is faster for a larger `dict`: `python -m timeit -s "d = dict(zip(range(20), range(20)))" "zip(d.values(), d.keys())"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.5 usec per loop`

`python -m timeit -s "d = dict(zip(range(20), range(20)))" "[(y, x) for x, y in d.items()]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.39 usec per loop`

Comment: @jamylak I used `range(100)`, so that might be the explanation.

Comment: @lazyr Yeah well I was inclined to believe you since I would expect list comps to be slower, seems that it really starts to show as the data set becomes larger.